# Don’t know what this means (Derivative)

Tags: derivatives

I was hoping to get a little help here. :)

I have this equation:

$$\left. \frac{\Bbb d}{\Bbb d\varepsilon} f(\varepsilon) \right|_{\varepsilon =\mu}$$

What I’m not sure about is what the $\varepsilon=\mu$ in the end of the “|” means?
Is it just that, in whatever function I have, I just replace $\varepsilon$ with $\mu$?

So if I have like:

$$f(\varepsilon)=\sqrt{\varepsilon }(\varepsilon-u),$$

then I just replace $\varepsilon$ with $\mu$, and in this case I get 0, or does it mean, that I have to take the derivative of the function with respect to $\mu$ and not  $\varepsilon$?
Or am I totally missing it? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Evaluate *after* differentiation, or any other operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the derivative (or whatever operation), *then* evaluate the result with the condition in the subscript.

Answer (score 2):

It means “plug in $\mu$ wherever you see $\varepsilon$ *after* you take the derivative.” In a different notation, it means $f'(\mu)$, where $f'(\varepsilon)=\frac{\Bbb d}{\Bbb d \varepsilon} f(\varepsilon)$.